# zfs filesystem: ls on one dir yields Input/output error. "zpool status" good "smartctl -l selftest" on all devs good. What next?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems, zfs

"Inherited" maintenance of lab Ubuntu server 16.04 system with zfs filesystem. The zfs part is new to me. Getting I/O error with ls for a specific directory but everything looks clean. "zpool  status" happy "smartctl -l selftest" happy on all devs. I would normally worry. What should I do next? Yes filesystem a little full. Weirdly not getting error in system log (dmesg) from I/O error. Maybe it's a zfs thing?

```
(base) root@tacitus:/home/obl# ls Phil
ls: cannot open directory 'Phil': Input/output error

(base) root@tacitus:/home/obl# uname -a
Linux tacitus 4.4.0-141-generic #167-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 5 10:40:15 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

(base) root@tacitus:/home/obl# df .
Filesystem       1K-blocks        Used  Available Use% Mounted on
data           29970265472 28567412096 1402853376  96% /home

(base) root@tacitus:/home/obl# zpool  status
  pool: data
 state: ONLINE
  scan: scrub repaired 0 in 39h18m with 0 errors on Mon Nov  9 15:42:45 2020
config:

    NAME                                         STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    data                                         ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-0                                   ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-HGST_HDN728080ALE604_R6GS4HTY-part7  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-HGST_HDN728080ALE604_R6GS1HYY-part7  ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-1                                   ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-HGST_HDN728080ALE604_R6GS1NBY-part1  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-HGST_HDN728080ALE604_R6GRTJGY-part1  ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-2                                   ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdc                                      ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdf                                      ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors


(base) root@tacitus:/home/obl# sudo smartctl -l selftest /dev/sda
smartctl 6.5 2016-01-24 r4214 [x86_64-linux-4.4.0-141-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     22250         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     21247         -
# 3  Short offline       Completed without error       00%       147         -

(base) root@tacitus:/home/obl# sudo smartctl -l selftest /dev/sdb
smartctl 6.5 2016-01-24 r4214 [x86_64-linux-4.4.0-141-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     22250         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     21248         -

(base) root@tacitus:/home/obl# sudo smartctl -l selftest /dev/sdc
smartctl 6.5 2016-01-24 r4214 [x86_64-linux-4.4.0-141-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      8311         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      7308         -

(base) root@tacitus:/home/obl# sudo smartctl -l selftest /dev/sdd
smartctl 6.5 2016-01-24 r4214 [x86_64-linux-4.4.0-141-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     22250         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     21247         -

(base) root@tacitus:/home/obl# sudo smartctl -l selftest /dev/sde
smartctl 6.5 2016-01-24 r4214 [x86_64-linux-4.4.0-141-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     22250         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     21247         -

(base) root@tacitus:/home/obl# sudo smartctl -l selftest /dev/sdf
smartctl 6.5 2016-01-24 r4214 [x86_64-linux-4.4.0-141-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      8311         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      7308         -

(base) root@tacitus:/home/obl# dmesg | tail
[   27.932402] audit: type=1400 audit(1605539563.228:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/ippusbxd" pid=2575 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   27.938559] audit: type=1400 audit(1605539563.232:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session" pid=2564 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   28.242146] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp4s0f0: link is not ready
[   28.326252] cgroup: new mount options do not match the existing superblock, will be ignored
[   30.742336] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp4s0f1: link is not ready
[   30.842395] e1000e: enp4s0f0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: None
[   30.870143] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp4s0f1: link is not ready
[   30.870205] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp4s0f0: link becomes ready
[13121.872076] perf interrupt took too long (2513 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 50000
[40206.668058] perf interrupt took too long (5006 > 5000), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 25000
```

Comment: "zpool status" shows the last scrub finish date. I am wondering if damage can happened after this and if this can be anyhow discovered from logs (sudo dmesg;grep -Ri XY /var/log; your app log). If it happened after last scrub, i would run it again (sudo zpool resilver;sudo zpool scrub poolname), though maybe this will be useless as the errors are permanent and in case this was no redundant storage setup (raidz?). I am noob in zfs.

Comment: SOLVED: zfs has its own separate quota command which I did not realize and the user had gone above his quota. The message one gets:  "Input/output error" is very very unfortunate because on a filesystem like ext4 it would mean something bad like a possible imminent HW failure.